# Write to file bit by bit

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, fstream

I'm implementing an entropy coding module in C++.

The code produces a stream of 0s and 1s that I would like to output to a file.

Since only whole bytes can be written (?), some caching is needed. I was thinking of something like this:

```
struct out_cache_t {
    uint8_t cache = 0;
    uint8_t count = 0;
};

inline void cached_output(const int bit, out_cache_t &out_cache, std::ofstream &out) {
    out_cache.cache <<= 1;
    out_cache.cache |= bit;
    out_cache.count += 1;
    if (out_cache.count == 8) {
        out.write((char*)&out_cache.cache, 1);
        out_cache.count = 0;
    }
}

void encode(...) {
  out_cache_t out_cache;
  std::ofstream out("output.txt");
  // ... do encoding ...
  if ( ... need to write 1 ... ) {
    cached_output(1, out_cache, out);
  } else if ( ... need to write 0 ... ) {
    cached_output(0, out_cache, out);
  }
  // ... more stuff ...
}
```

But I was wondering, is there some easier or potentially more efficient way built into the std lib? What do people usually do in this scenario?

(Note that I'm usually programming in Python so I'm not very familiar with the ways of C++)

Comment: you could try `std::bitset` - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset

Comment: @MarcStröbel Thanks for the pointer, however, how would bitset<8> be different from using a uint8?

Comment: just a cleaner api

Comment: Your code looks good.  Perhaps a uint32_t or uint64_t would lead to more efficient disk writes.  Also, you need to implement a flush of the last bits if the total is not a multiple of your cache size.  Be sure to left justify them before writing or you will get stale data in the high bits.